# What is the default value when max_rate_per_instance attribute is not specified when balancing mode is Utilization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-load-balancer

When using the backend service compute resource and having the balancing mode as Utilization, since the attribute max_rate_per_instance is optional in this case, and if we dont specify it, would GCP use any default value for this?

Also, What would be the maximum possible value for this attribute if we do specify it?

Thanks you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what type of Load Balancer are used, assuming that you are using external HTTP(S) Load Balancer, the balancing mode can be Utilization or Rate. The [utilization balancing mode](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#utilization_balancing_mode) has no mandatory target capacity. You have a number of options that depend on the type of backend, if you don't specify it, the default value of maximum backend utilization is 80% to consider a backend as healthy

An additional control to manage your maximum backend utilization or RPS. If you want your instances to operate at a max 80% backend utilization, set your balancing mode to 80% max backend utilization and your capacity to 100%. If you want to cut instance utilization by half, set your balancing mode to 80% max backend utilization and your capacity to 50%.